# JSF how add a control on the first url

Tags: jsf

I have to implement a new feature in my existing JSF application.
As it is now, there is a feature for searching a objects. The normal flow is: fill in some form parameters and see the detailed object page after submitting the form.
Now I have to find a way to go to the detailed object page via a link which arrives through an email.
In the link there are some parameters, useful to find the object, but if the object doesn't exist I would to forward the user to a courtesy page.
How could I manage this thing?
thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the job in constructor or `@PostConstruct` method of the bean which is associated with the view and use the `rendered` attribute to render page fragment/include conditionally.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    someObject = someDAO.find(someParam);
}
```

with

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.someObject != null}">
    Found
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.someObject == null}">
    Not gound
</h:panelGroup>
```

Or use `ExternalContext#redirect()` to redirect to another view.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    someObject = someDAO.find(someParam);
    if (someObject == null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("notfound.jsf");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi BalusC, thank you for your quick answer. I did it in the way you wrote and it works just for the first link. I have several links in my email and the init method is executed only for the first link. Have you any idea how to manage it? thank you in advance.

Comment: Put the bean in the request scope.

Comment: It already has the request scope. I'm starting to think that I have some configuration problem... My request beans act as session. Do you have any idea about the cause? thx

Comment: Maybe it might be usefull for someone else. I solved putting the parameter concurrentDOMViews in the web.xml to true. <context-param>
  <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>